# How to install Theme in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can not figure how to connect this template to the rails app. A lot of files, which one I do not know which one to put. Who practiced install templates in rails can teach me?

**Theme Demo online:** http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_1/LTR/default/index.html

**Theme for download:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Mjt-qLZKiqa3Zad1oxVGs0Zms

Comment: Oh boy. This is gonna be tough. I haven't personally done this kind of thing before, but I think you should start reading about the [directory structure of a rails application](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-quick-study-of-the-rails-directory-structure/). Your folders of interest should include (but not limited to): `app/assets`, `app/views`, `vendor/`.

Comment: Rails is not a cms like WP where you just install themes. You will have to do this all manually I'm afraid.

Comment: In folders many files, can you download and help to write mini guide where to put files?

Comment: @ViktorianII Stackoverflow is not a codewriting service. If you have a specific problem you're facing ask that question and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow steps to integrate theme:

1. Add js files under /assets/javascript
2. Add css files under /assets/stylesheets
3. Move all images to images folder
4. create a controller and add html pages in /views folder
5. Be sure that all js/css/images be load in application layout.